# uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token . jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

First of all let me say I'm new to jQuery. I've tried to search for this error on StackOver flow but did not get any answers. I've created a function in jQuery but this is the error I'm getting from Chrome.
**uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token . jquery**

```
jQuery.fn.viewC = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
    alert("something");
    });
}
```

And I'm trying to call this from another function like this

```
$("#sourceId").click(function() {
    $(this).viewC();
})
```

Is this the correct way to call a function? And finally what is difference between

```
_tabChanged : function(container) {
    //some code
},
```

and

```
jQuery.fn.viewC = function(){
    //some code
}
```

Are both the same ways to create a function?

Comment: Why have you switched between calling jQuery as `$` and as `jQuery`?

Comment: how do you import jQuery? You must declare it before calling any javascript that uses it.

Comment: it is working check this link http://jsfiddle.net/uU4mk/1/

Comment: did you add jquery in your code

Comment: All the imports are done. I've now changed it to $

Answer (score 0):

It is a little strange you are using both `$` and `jQuery` in one piece of code. Usually you would use `$` to refer to jQuery.

Try this:

```
$.fn.viewC = function(){
  return this.each(function(){
  alert("something");
});
```

}

Also, I am not sure if `this.each` will work (not if it is meant to be jQuery).

Comment: Can you remove the `each` part and only show the `alert`?

Comment: So the code would look like
$.fn.viewC = function(){
    alert("somethig");
}

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your html with javascript?

Comment: hmmm the code is quite long. The code I'm working on contains only jQuery. The HTML is created dynamically. It's too big to be put on jsfiddle. sorry

Comment: Can you narrow it down to the lines where the problem is? Show us the references to external js files, etc. Those are the most important.